# I want to save the data in the dataframe that I created

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, save

```
for row in soup.find('table',{'class':'tableagmark_new'}).find_all('td'):
    print(row.text)
```

This is the command that I am giving and getting this output:

```
                                                1
                                            

Agra


Agra


Potato


Desi


FAQ


1000


1150


1080


30 Jan 2020


                                                2
                                            

Agra


Fatehabad


Potato


Desi


FAQ


800


900


850


30 Jan 2020


                                                3
                                            

Agra


Fatehpur Sikri


Potato


Local


FAQ


1100


1260


1190


30 Jan 2020


                                                4
                                            

Agra


Jagnair


Potato


Desi


FAQ


1120


1200


1160


30 Jan 2020


                                                5
                                            

Agra


Jarar


Potato


Desi


FAQ


760


840


800


30 Jan 2020


                                                6
                                            

Agra


Khairagarh


Potato


Desi


FAQ


900


1000


950


30 Jan 2020


                                                7
                                            

Agra


Samsabad


Potato


Local


FAQ


1000


1200


1100


30 Jan 2020
```

​I just want to know how do i save this data in the dataframe that I created:

```
agrilink_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["SL.no.", "District Name", "Market Name", "Commodity","Variety","Grade","Min_price(Rs/Quintal)","Max_price(Rs/Quintal)",'Modal_price(Rs/Quintal)','Price date'])
```

With each iteration I get one output, like in my first iteration I get 1 as output and then agra in second iteration and so on. I want to save result of each iteration in a columns. and again from (2) in a different row and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
L=[]
data=[]
count=0
for row in soup.find('table',{'class':'tableagmark_new'}).find_all('td'):

        x=(row.text.strip('\n\r\t": '))
        data.append(x)
        if len(data)==10:
            L.append(data)
            data=[]
    

agrilink_data=pd.DataFrame(L,columns=["SL.no.", "District Name", "Market Name","Commodity","Variety","Grade","Min_price(Rs/Quintal)","Max_price(Rs/Quintal)",'Modal_price(Rs/Quintal)','Price date'])
agrilink_data1=agrilink_data1.append(agrilink_data)
```